# jquery hover/change css property help

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I'm new to jQuery and I'm looking for a simple script (or maybe there's a simpler method) where if a user hovers over an element, another element's css property changes.

For example,
hover over this image and "border-bottom" on another element changes color or something, etc.
thanks

Answer (score 14):

use the hover property

```
$('#elementA').hover(function(){
    $('#elementB').addClass('active');
},function(){
    $('#elementB').removeClass('active');
});
```

then style the active class in your css

Comment: Now he has both the documentation and an example?

Comment: Good point. (Wasn't trying to insult you...I just like when people learn why they are doing what they are doing...ya know?)

Comment: Absolutely agree! Especially with jQuery... to easy to jump in and have no clue.

Answer (score 6):

What have you tried so far?

Here is the [jQuery documentation on hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).  Basically, provide a selector to the object that you want to hover over (and leave, if you don't want a permanent effect).  Then, inside the event's function, select the object that you want changed and update its [CSS settings](http://api.jquery.com/css/). (Or, if you have a class for it written, [update to the new class](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).)

If you want to add some code that you have tried to write (update your post), I would be more than happy to help you with it.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#test").hover(function()
                {
                    $("#test2").css("background-color", "blue");
                }, function()
                {
                    $("#test2").css("background-color", "green");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test" style="border:solid 1px black;" >
            Hover Over Me
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="test2" style="background-color:green;">
            Test2
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```